# JQuery UI dialog not displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm trying to display a "dialog" with JQuery UI when i click on a button, but it isn't displaying. Is there a problem in my program?

Here is my code:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#mode").click(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="mode" type="button" class="btn-modalita link">change mode</button>

<div id="dialog" title="Empty the recycle bin?">
  <p>
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:12px 12px 20px 0;">
    </span>you are changing mode. Are you sure?
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: You haven't initialized your dialog.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Did you include jQuery UI?

Comment: Yes, and I confirmed checking if(JQuery.ui) was true

Comment: Thank you for telling me, I didn't know i should have iniztialized it. Should inizialize it on button click or when the page is loaded?

Comment: you need to initialize and hide it before you actually start interacting with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initialize and hide the dialog, then you're good.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#dialog").dialog({autoOpen: false});
  
  $("#mode").click(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<button id="mode" type="button" class="btn-modalita link">change mode</button>

<div id="dialog" title="Empty the recycle bin?">
  <p>
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:12px 12px 20px 0;">
    </span>you are changing mode. Are you sure?
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Or initialize `$("#dialog").dialog({ autoOpen: false});`

Comment: yup yup. prettier that way, too. I was realizing that there was the option, just had to update. Thanks, @npearson!

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm sure it is the solution, but it didn't work to me. Should i maybe inizialize my dialog in JS before creating it in HTML?

Comment: what is it doing or not doing?

Comment: I tried to display the error and it says  "TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function". Could there be a reason for that? I'm using Chrome

Comment: I found out the problem was because of conflict between libraries. I fixed it chianging the $ symbol into another to avoid conflict. Your code is working thank you very much for your time

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are missing on there and also make sure you are using Correct version of jquery

```
$(function() {
  $("#mode").on('click', function(){
    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
  });
});
```

Comment: Nah, the `.click()` function does the same as `.on("click",...)`

Answer (score 0):

I worked in Jsfiddle and it worked fine here is the code:

```js
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      show: {
        effect: "blind",
        duration: 1000
      },
      hide: {
        effect: "explode",
        duration: 1000
      }
    });

    $( "#mode" ).on( "click", function() {
      $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
    });
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/eggplant/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<button id="mode" type="button" class="btn-modalita link">change mode</button>

<div id="dialog" title="Empty the recycle bin?">
  <p>
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:12px 12px 20px 0;">
    </span>you are changing mode. Are you sure?
  </p>
</div>
```